# DNS error on laptop when tethered to non-rooted Android 5.1 device

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, internet, tethering, dns

I am trying to hotspot my laptop from a non-rooted Android 5.1 phone (ZTE A110). On IPv4 and IPv6 I get Connection Status: Enabled - with high speed quality - but No Internet Access.  When I run Windows network diagnostics it says: The DNS server may be experiencing problems, contact your ISP.  However that is pointless as the phone itself is connecting fine to the internet.  What am I doing wrong please?  (Tethering Worked fine last week to the same laptop from the same ISP but a different phone running Android 4.4).

Comment: Hi, did you found how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the developer options on your phone, and set the usb config to RNDIS manually (this should happen automatically when you set on usb tether, but [driver issues?]) If that does not do it, go for the USB debugging option, --not that either?
 OEM unlocking is next.. (these are all in the same developer menu)..

-I am not 100% if the OEM unlock is just to enable the bootloader, but when fixing this, I remembered a nasty little tid-bit how yankee phones' ability to tether is sometimes disabled, just to enable Service Providers to sell two internet-plans instead of one.. 
So, now all fired up, fighting for my rights, I just went all ham on all of the above, and now my tethering experience is smoother than ever.